# Leaflet marker not showing on production

Tags: javascript

I have been working on building website using live-server but as I try to bundle it with parcel, `your text`marker is not showing up on production environment.

I have googled a bit and learned that this is a well known bug for leaflet and there are some solutions to this but I’m quite new to all this(learning Javascript at the moment and this project I’m working on is vanila js) so the solutions I found is either not for my case(using other framework) or I can’t understand like half of them.

Can anyone help me out on this please?

This is in my head in index.html

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI=" crossorigin="" />
    <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM=" crossorigin=""></script>
```

And this is the code in my script

```
 // Render initial marker and popup
    const initIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: 'current.png',
      iconSize: [80, 80],
      iconAnchor: [8, 8],
    });
    const marker = L.marker(coords, { icon: initIcon }).addTo(this.#map);
    marker
      .bindPopup(
        L.popup({
          minWidth: 240,
          autoClose: false,
          className: 'initial-popup',
        }).setContent(
          `This is your <strong>current position</strong>.<br> Click on the map to add a workout`
        )
      )
      .openPopup();
```

I’ve tried to download the leaflet css file directly(download the file, unzip it, add to the folder then change the html head link for using a downloaded version) but I just get this massive error that it cant be built for some reason or that they can’t find the entry point, even though the path seems to be right.

Comment: In te iconUrl yo have to specifit the path, in local this can works, but the server needs to know where is the image, if is in the same folder use iconUrl: '/icon.png'.  if you dont know how relative path works, look this  [link](https://www.w3schools.com/Html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: That path I put on my code, I copied the relative path and pasted it as it’s in the same folder. Also I’ve tried your solution(so with adding / ) doesn’t seem to work t.t any other recommendations?